# No sound in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, sound, external-soundcard

I have a multi OS computer (Windows XP, Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 14.04).
Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows XP are 32 bit systems in separate partitions.
Ubuntu 14.04 is a 64 bit system in it's own partition.
I have sound in Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows XP, but not in Ubuntu 12.04.
On board audio is disabled in the Bios.
Creative Sound Audigy SE card is properly installed.
How do I solve this problem?